# I'm attempting to place a small 'About Us' footer just above the real footer, but can't seem to get it to come up on the page

Tags: html, css

I'm relatively new to this!
I've tried several different times with different names, information, etc., but it simply won't move to where I want it to.

HTML

```
<div id="about-footer"class="about-footer">
</div>
```

CSS

```
about-footer {
position: absolute;
top: 600px;
width: 100%;
height: 300px;
background-color: dimgrey;
```

}

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a `.` in front of your selector.

```
.about-footer {
```

The positioning absolute is also dependant on your parent element. If your element does not apear where you would expect it, try setting `position: relative;` on the parent element.

Comment: I gave it a go but it didn't work:( Is there anything else I could try? Maybe there's something wrong with the HTML, I'm very unsure.

Comment: @tombros That depends on the rest of your HTML. The code you provided with my edits work. https://jsfiddle.net/x7ukb25m/ Try to pin down the exact problem by creating a minimum code demo in a jsfiddle.